# Question about site rules

Tags: discussion, rules

Is the stack overflow site an appropriate place to post several documents of code and say, "here's the problem but I don't know what's wrong with it?"

Comment: Nooooope nope nope nope. You need to be able to isolate your Q to a minimal example. Minimal does mean minimal, so ' several documents'is WAYYYY too much

Comment: You may want to re-read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and than [edit] your question if help did not cover your case.

Comment: If you don't know how to debug your code, stop everything and learn how.

Comment: I wonder how one could even assume that something like this would be ok on any site on the internet where you don't pay the people to do that. Several files and one should do that for you for free? Wow.

Comment: @Tom I'm a natural citizen of Math exchange, where people are more willing to look through your work and tell you what you did wrong. I know it's a lot of work to look through code so I suspected that it might not fly here.

Comment: I *hope* that also depends on the size of the submitted question and if one posts a block of 150 math formulas  with the question "where is the issue", then it will be "too broad". Especially since this is hardly helpful for future readers since it is unlikely that they will find that question and have the same context.

Comment: That's true. I was surprised at the backlash I got for for asking this question. -13? Yikes! But I realize now I gave a bad impression of the question I wanted to ask. It is not so broad as I let on. I am fairly sure the problem is with pointers and I have a good idea of which class they are located in.

Comment: Also, to more directly address what you said, its less formulas and more proofs. Occasionally I have had a proof that clearly proved something that wasn't true but I didn't know what the problem was. In a case like that, you really have no choice but to post the whole proof and say, "where did I mess up?" But usually, for a professional mathematician, it's relatively easy to spot the error, even when it's complicated. Code is obviously different.

Comment: @Will do you know a good place I can learn to debug code online? I'm still learning to program so that would be really helpful for me :)

Comment: @ZacharyF *"I was surprised at the backlash I got for for asking this question. -13? Yikes!"* This is a meta and these downvotes mostly mean disagreement. So the voters are trying to say: don't do what you've asked about. The answers just used text to say the same. So, nothing to worry about.

Comment: @ZacharyF It all depends on what you are doing.  Interestingly, internet search engines are very effective for locating debugging instructions for the language/tool that you use.  For example, if I search Bing for "how to debug in visual studio" I get this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx which is the start of an entire guide for learning how to debug code in visual studio.  In addition, you can find wonderful books on amazon about using your IDE.  Simply search for it by name and sort the results by user rating.  Buy the first couple and read them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the close dialog

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If you aren't familiar enough with your own code to narrow the problem down to a few lines, then no one is going to be able to help you.  Nor is anyone going to be willing to dig through your code base for clues.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't know what the problem is with it (and you have both the code *and* the context), what chance do a group of strangers have with even less?

It's important for you as an asker to narrow down as much as possible your specific question, which includes paring down the actual issue as much as you can **on your own** before asking us.

We don't really appreciate giant code dumps and questions which state, "I don't know what's going on", since it doesn't convey to us anything that we can truly help out with or build on.

So, I would encourage you to include ***as much information as possible***, including narrowing down the problem, before asking.  Who knows - by isolating issues like that, you may stumble upon the answer without having to ask Stack Overflow!